# How to access this array's elements (iOS objective-C)?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following array defined:

```
NSArray *array = @[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.latitude], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.longitude]];
[tappedCoordinates addObject:array];
```

This is a multi-dimensional array (2 entries per each element). How may I retrieve the first and second entry per each element in the array?

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't creating a `NSArray` of `CGPoint` values using `NSValue` ?

Comment: no there is not.

Comment: Or just storing the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` directly in the `NSValue` assuming that's what `coordinate` is.

Comment: Why use such difficult syntax? Just do: `NSArray *array = @[@(coordinated.latitude), @(coordinate.longitude)];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 1st element of array try this :

```
 NSArray *array = [tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0];
```

To read elements of 1st array of array :

```
  NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:0]);   
  NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:0]);
```

OR

```
  NSLog(@"%@",[[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]);   
  NSLog(@"%@",[[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Answer for your comment (Expected):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position;
for (int i = 0; i <= [tappedCoordinates count]-1; i++)
{
    position.latitude = [[[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    position.longitude = [[[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = position;
    marker.map = _mapView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not even wrap the coordinate in `NSValue`? There is a dedicated method:

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:coordinate];
[tappedCoordinates addObject: value];
```

And to get the coordinate back:

```
NSValue *value = array[0];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [value MKCoordinateValue];
CLLocationDegrees latitude = coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = coordinate.longitude;
```

**Important note**: To use this API you need to import `MapKit`.

Comment: How can I wrap both coordinates?

Comment: The `CLLocationCoordinate2D` struct includes both `latitude` and `longitude`. You get rid of creating a new coordinate with `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake`

Comment: Got an error for this. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Comment: `valueWithMKCoordinate` has been introduced in iOS6. It's supposed to work. Have you imported the `CoreLocation` framework?

Comment: I just tested quickly `CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(1.0, 2.0);  NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:coordinate]; NSLog(@"%@", value);`. Works fine.

Comment: Well @vadian, it also gives me a compiler error when trying to use `[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, longi)]`. Says "No known class method for selector `valueWithMKCoordinate`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You need also to import `MapKit`. It's a category of `NSValue` implemented in `MapKit`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
  NSLog(@"%@",[[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]);   
  NSLog(@"%@",[[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]); 
    //This will print NSNumber object from which you can get lat and lang
```

OR

```
 NSLog(@"%@",tappedCoordinates[0][0]);
  NSLog(@"%@",tappedCoordinates[0][1]);//Take care about conversion back to coordinate from NSNumber.
```

In case for for loop

```
for(int i=0;i< tappedCoordinates.count;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<[[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:i] count];j++){
       NSLog(@"%@",tappedCoordinates[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to put them into a variable, it says incompatible type (id). How can I fix that?    for (int i = 0; i <= [tappedCoordinates count]-1; i++) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D latitude = [[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D longitude = [[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1];

        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is a simple array of tapped `CGPoints`. You could try writing

```
[tappedCoordinates addObject [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)]]
```

And then to get a value:

```
//or get any other position from the array :D
NSValue *value = [tappedCoordinates firstObject];

CGPoint coordinate = [value CGPointValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Save latitude and longitude value in array as this

```
NSMutableArray *tappedCoordinates =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDictionary *dict =  @{
  @"latitude" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.latitude],
  @"longitude" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:coordinate.longitude],
 };

[tappedCoordinates addObject:dict];

NSLog(@"latitude is---%@",[[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"latitude"]);
NSLog(@"longitude is---%@",[[tappedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"longitude"]);
```